# Problem with unity after latest update

Tags: unity

You see after the last update all my GUI is not working: I don't have launcher or top panel menu and no window arrows are showed to. I tried to reset Unity setting by using dconf-tool   and tried to reinstall Unity, but nothing helps.

Comment: What version are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to my experience, (I’ve destroyed my Unity twice ever!) there’s an inappropriate graphical update. Do you add any PPA for Unity which may contain an update for nux, for example? Anyway, all you need is (1) detect what causes the problem, and (2) remove the experimental/unsupported packages and/or add the default ones.

So, for now, open a Terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and type `software-center` to open Ubuntu Software Center. Then go to History and see what packages are upgraded or removed. Edit your question and write them down or make a screenshot if possible.

If you added a PPA, purging the PPA would be the simplest way possible through ppa-purge. You need to install it first: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`